# Writing and reading data between two nodejs servers using node serial port

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, buffer, node-serialport

I would like to send "Hello world" from one nodejs server to another using node-serialport.  I have verified that the radios connecting the two are connected and sending info because they keep displaying buffer information after running my current code.
here is what I have so far.

server1

```
// Import dependencies
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = require("@serialport/parser-readline");

var sf = require('sf');

//SerialPort.list(function (err, results) {
//  if (err) {
//    throw err;
//  }

  SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
      console.log(port.path);
      console.log(port.pnpId);
      console.log(port.manufacturer);
    });
  });


// Defining the serial port
const port = new SerialPort('COM3',{baudRate: 9600}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Port Error: ', err.message)
  }
})

port.write('main screen turn on', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message)
  }
  console.log('message written')
})

// Read data that is available but keep the stream in "paused mode"
port.on('readable', function () {
  console.log('Data:', port.read())
})

// Switches the port into "flowing mode"
port.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Data:', data)
})

// Pipe the data into another stream (like a parser or standard out)
const lineStream = port.pipe(new Readline())

lineStream.on('data', console.log)
```

server 2

```
// Import dependencies
// in Ubuntu need to run command: sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0 to open port for use
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = require("@serialport/parser-readline");

var stoploop = true;

// Defining the serial port
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error: ', err.message)
  }
})


port.write('chicken butt', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message)
    }
    console.log('message written')
})

// port.write("hello?");
// Read data that is available but keep the stream in "paused mode"
port.on('readable', function () {
  console.log('Data:', port.read())
})

// Switches the port into "flowing mode"
port.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Data:', data)
})

// Pipe the data into another stream (like a parser or standard out)
const lineStream = port.pipe(new Readline())
```

any help or even an example of how to send hello world between the two would be greatly appreciated! please let me know if any more info is needed.

edit : I recently tried doing something like

```
port.on('data', (data) => {
  try {
    console.log(data.toString());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops');
  }
});
```

this is taking data that used to appear as <buffer # # # # #> and turning it into an odd string like "(
))))    ) )      )))
!)☺)!)))        )  )
)(☺!�"

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself!
I was using the wrong baudRate, and also needed to stringify the data being sent as a JSON string